# Laravel 4: Can't put methods into models?

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-4

i always got the error

```
Non-static method MyModel::getCollection() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

Even just the empty method fails:

```
<?php

class MyModel extends Eloquent {

    public $table = 'my_table';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getCollection()

    {

        //return $this->...

    }

}
```

So can't i put methods into Models or are they "wrong" there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a `non-static` method using static (`::`) syntax but in `Laravel` you may declare a `scope` method like this:

```
public function scopeGetCollection($query)
{
    // use $query
    //return $query
}
```

Then you may call it from your `Controller` like this:

```
Modelname::getCollection(); // Replace Modelname with real model name
```

Comment: Is this just a Laravel-thing on the Model-folder or everywhere? So without scopes no fun? ;)

Comment: @user3763555, This (scope) is only `Laravel`'s feature in `Eloquent Model` :-)

Comment: But is this valid also for non-Laravel-coding in PHP: "You can't call a non-static method using static (::) syntax"

Comment: Yes but I'm talking about `scope` method which is only for `Laravel`.